# Azure Policy like where case sensitive

Tags: azure-policy

I'm looking to form a policy that, like "matchInsensitively" and "match" are case sensitive but with something like the like conditional operator.

With match I have to define if the statement has either a character, digit, or "." in place but I want to be able to define the actual string, ideally with a leading wildcard.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a contains. There are various conditions you can leverage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#conditions